# Crashed Foundation EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS

Tags: ios, foundation

We are having a crash in Foundation, but we are unable to detect what could be the problem. We think that maybe an animation could trigger this problem.

Has anybody encounter this kind of crash? Here is the trace of the problem.

```
 Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x1dfc44e6 objc_msgSend + 5
1  Foundation                     0x1f7b0e77 -[_NSConcreteObservation dealloc] + 96
2  libobjc.A.dylib                0x1dfd1195 objc_object::sidetable_release(bool) + 238
3  Foundation                     0x1f679e9d empty + 32
4  Foundation                     0x1f5d4787 -[NSConcreteMapTable removeAllItems] + 76
5  UIKit                          0x246e5259 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _clearLayoutVariableObservationsOnlyToSupportTAMICChange:] + 56
6  UIKit                          0x23efaa0b __57-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:]_block_invoke + 380
7  Foundation                     0x1f5f7b03 -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 262
8  UIKit                          0x23df6e8b -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:] + 220
9  UIKit                          0x23efab91 __57-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:]_block_invoke_2 + 170
10 UIKit                          0x23efaaa7 __57-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:]_block_invoke + 536
11 Foundation                     0x1f5f7b03 -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 262
12 UIKit                          0x23df6e8b -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:] + 220
13 UIKit                          0x23efab91 __57-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:]_block_invoke_2 + 170
14 UIKit                          0x23efaaa7 __57-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:]_block_invoke + 536
15 Foundation                     0x1f5f7b03 -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 262
16 UIKit                          0x23df6e8b -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:] + 220
17 UIKit                          0x23df6737 __45-[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:]_block_invoke + 92
18 Foundation                     0x1f5f7b03 -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 262
19 UIKit                          0x23df6607 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:] + 754
20 UIKit                          0x240e8949 __UIViewWasRemovedFromSuperview + 154
21 UIKit                          0x23df57a5 -[UIView(Hierarchy) removeFromSuperview] + 1188
22 UIKit                          0x24768167 __46-[UIInputWindowController invalidateInputView]_block_invoke + 120
23 UIKit                          0x241872b9 -[UIResponder _preserveResponderOverridesWhilePerforming:] + 108
24 UIKit                          0x247680eb -[UIInputWindowController invalidateInputView] + 108
25 UIKit                          0x24768a17 -[UIInputWindowController changeToInputViewSet:] + 240
26 UIKit                          0x24769d91 __43-[UIInputWindowController setInputViewSet:]_block_invoke.1331 + 26
27 UIKit                          0x2476382d __77-[UIInputWindowController moveFromPlacement:toPlacement:starting:completion:]_block_invoke.932 + 404
28 UIKit                          0x23e3363b -[UIViewAnimationBlockDelegate _didEndBlockAnimation:finished:context:] + 440
29 UIKit                          0x23e33109 -[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:] + 214
30 UIKit                          0x23e32f91 -[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:] + 128
31 QuartzCore                     0x21c06ee7 CA::Layer::run_animation_callbacks(void*) + 252
32 libdispatch.dylib              0x1e3fa083 _dispatch_client_callout + 22
33 libdispatch.dylib              0x1e3fe5fd _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 890
34 CoreFoundation                 0x1ed104a7 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 8
35 CoreFoundation                 0x1ed0e78f __CFRunLoopRun + 1422
36 CoreFoundation                 0x1ec5d533 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 486
37 CoreFoundation                 0x1ec5d341 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
38 GraphicsServices               0x20434bfd GSEventRunModal + 156
39 UIKit                          0x23e65e67 -[UIApplication _run] + 574
40 UIKit                          0x23e60591 UIApplicationMain + 150
41 App                            0xb3c158 main (AppDelegate.swift:22)
42 libdispatch.dylib              0x1e42750b (Missing)
```

Comment: Set an exception breakpoint.  Then investigate the source around where it breaks.

Comment: "objc_msgSend" is often a sign of sending a message to a deallocated object.  Turning on zombies might give you clues.

Comment: @danh thank you, unfortunately the problem is presented in a production environment, I'm unable to set the breakpoints :/ Do you know if there's a way to log those exceptions (i.e. .txt)?

Comment: @PhillipMills thank you, I ran some tests with NSZombie but I didn't catch the error. Moreover, the app crashed due to memory, but I think that it was because Zombie retained the objects.